# How to implement iterator using trait

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I have a struct called Library, which has a vector of strings (titles). I have implemented an iterator for this. Here is my code.

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Library {
    books: Vec<String>
}

impl Iterator for Library {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to implement an Iterator using a trait, like this:

```
fn foo(x: Vec<u32>) -> impl Iterator<Item=u32> {
    //Unsure if correct method
    fn next() -> Option<...> {
       x.into_iter()....

    }
}
```

But I'm unsure of how to proceed in this case. Do I simply have to define a next() method again? That doesn't seem to be the case, according to other resources. Why is that? Shouldn't an iterator (which is being returned) have a next() method?

What is the general method for implementing an iterator this way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement Iterator trait for a struct containing an iterable field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277992/implement-iterator-trait-for-a-struct-containing-an-iterable-field)

Answer (score 8):

You wouldn't implement the trait directly on `Library`. The library is not an iterator, but it is something that could be iterated by an iterator.

Instead, just declare a method that returns an iterator, and you can simply return an iterator directly from your vector.  There is no need for a custom iterator implementation.  For example:

```
impl Library {
    fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&String> {
        self.books.iter()
    }
}
```

For your second case, you can turn the vector into an iterator using `into_iter()`, provided by the `IntoIterator` trait:

```
fn foo(x: Vec<u32>) -> impl Iterator<Item=u32> {
    x.into_iter()
}
```

Comment: Right, so the .into_iter() I understand. What if I had a more complicated type? Such as fn foo<A>(x: Vec<A>) -> impl Iterator<Item = (u32,A)>? I want the iterator to go through each element in x and return (0,A) or (1, A) based on some condition?

Comment: Similarly, what if I had fn foo(x: Vec<u32>) -> impl Iterator<Item = (u32, u32)>?

Comment: @DarrelGulseth That's where the standard iterator utilities like `.map()` come in. So you could do `x.into_iter().map(|v| /* some expression here */)`

Comment: @DarrelGulseth It all depends how you want to iterate that. If you want to flatten the nested vector into one iterator of `u32` then you just do `x.into_iter().flatten()`.

Comment: That offers a lot of clarity! Thanks.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth No problem. The `Iterator` trait provides dozens of such utilities. Using them you can do just about any sequence manipulation you can think of. It's very rare you need to implement your own iterator, unless you are implementing something like a paged API client or are implementing your own data structure from scratch.