# Best way to model storing an iterator for a vector inside same struct

Tags: rust

### Context

I'm a beginner, and, at a high level, what I want to do is store some mutable state (to power a state machine) in a struct with the following constraints

- Mutating the state doesn't require the entire struct to be `mut` (since I'd have to update a ton of callsites to be mut + I don't want every field to be mutable)
- The state is represented as an enum, and can, in the right state, store a way to index into the correct position in a vec that's in the same struct

I came up with two different approaches/examples that seem quite complicated and I want to see if there's a way to simplify. Here's some playgrounds that minimally reproduce what I'm exploring

1. [Using a Cell and a usize](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d58d57e44f585b8aada7238085effbb8)

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum S {
    A,
    B(usize),
}

struct Test {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: Cell<S>,
}
```

where usage look like this

```
println!("{}", t.a[index]);
t.b.set(S::B(index + 1));
```

2. [Using a RefCell and an iterator](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8af3036d98e6649367a20b173c3705b8)

```
enum S<'a> {
    A,
    B(Iter<'a, i32>),
}

struct Test<'a> {
    a: Vec<i32>,
    b: RefCell<S<'a>>,
}
```

where usage looks like this

```
println!("{}", iter.next().unwrap());
```

### Questions

1. Is there a better way to model this in general vs. what I've tried?
2. I like approach #2 with the iterator better in theory since it feels cleaner, but I don't like how it introduces explicit lifetime annotations into the struct...in the actual codebase I'm working on, I'd need to update a ton of callsites to add the lifetime annotation and the tiny bit of convenience doesn't seem worth it. Is there some way to do #2 without introducing lifetimes?

Comment: I think adding the lifetime annotations should be easily automatable and far better than having to maintain explicit calls to `set` to advance the home-brew iterator.

Comment: If the iterator stored in `b` references `a` this would be a self-referential struct, which [can't be easily done in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct). Approach #2 is non-viable without pinning.

Comment: What is your struct S for? It seems to act as Option where S::A is None.

Comment: @cdhowie hmm I see. How would you approach getting #2 to work? I read through the linked question and it seems like I have a lot of potential options...that being said I don't think keeping the state separate from the struct itself makes sense because it'd require the caller to create the state and pass it in to every function alongside the struct

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, but this answer might help you understand how you can store a generic iterator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68278323/5987669

Comment: I wonder if there really is a good reason which makes you want to avoid simply making the whole struct `mut`? If you think there should really be a part of your struct that should be mutable, and an other part that should not be mutable, maybe the best idea would simply be to split the struct into a mutable part and a non-mutable part. Also, you can restrain access to fields without `pub`, and just add a getter method if you really don't want them to be mutated.

Comment: @m0meni It depends exactly on what the rest of the implementation looks like. For example, if this is a forward-only iterator that never reads past elements then you can just use `Vec::into_iter()` to produce the iterator and not store the `Vec` at all.